# How to display the records from mysql table which is containing the '&' value

Tags: php, mysql

In my mysql table there are some records which I need to retrieve and show them in a page but my table has a column called company and it holds a value named AT & T when I'm queried and displaying the values instead of AT & T only AT is been displayed How to solve this?

Here is what I have tried

```
update tests set stages=\"$stages\", channel=\"$channel\", remarks=\"$remarks\",owner=\"$owner\",date1=\"$modified_on\",action_item=\"$acti‌​on_item\" where (organization=\"$organization\" && id=\"$rider_id\" && first_name=\"$first_name\")";
```

This is the command I'm using for updating based on the company name but values consisting of & in the company name are not updating

Comment: UPDATE does not display, SELECT does. No idea what this is about.

Comment: @Fred-ii-based on the update statment only I should display thera is no need to down vote for this. if you dont have an idea then just dont comment.

Comment: Dude, if you want to accuse me of anything, it's trying to help. Get real.

Comment: Plus, *"its not working"* isn't much to go on. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape values. So for example if you are using mysqli:

```
    //escape and htmlspecialchars
    $stages = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, htmlspecialchars($stages));
    $channel= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, htmlspecialchars($channel));
    etc...
```

Comment: If you are displaying your result in HTML you can change special characters like & to HTML format... so & will be &amp;. Maybe that's your problem.